# Why do I get +2 more culture for the Theater Square?

Tags: civilization-6

I played *Civilization VI* as Trajan (Rome) and created a theater square that gave me +3 culture:

[image: gave me +3 culture]

However, the adjacency bonus is only +1 and no citizen is occupying the district.

[image: no citizen is occupying]

Why do I get +2 more culture for the Theater Square?

Comment: hmm, what policy cards do you have in?

Answer (score 1):

I think it was due to a city-state prodivding +2 culture to Theater Districts.